# How to plot a surface into each subplot

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, surface

I would like to plot two surfaces into two subplots. So far the surfaces are drawn well, however all are plotted into the first subplot graph.

The code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

#...

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.winter,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
#ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
ax.set_xlabel(r'X')
ax.set_ylabel(r'Y')
ax.set_zlabel(r"Z-axis = weight $w(X,Y)$")

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
surf2 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, W, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.winter,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax2.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax2.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
ax2.set_xlabel(r'X')
ax2.set_ylabel(r'Y')
ax2.set_zlabel(r"Z-axis = approximated weight $w(X,Y)$")

fig.colorbar(surf2, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

In the result the right subplot graph is empty while the left one contains two surface. I would like to draw each surface into a separate graph area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to plot `surf2` on `ax2` (you currently plot it on `ax`)

```
surf2 = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, W, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.winter,
                         linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks. I completely overlooked this. Typical Copy and Paster error :)